# id:hover id in css ? is it possible?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, hover

Here is my html code

```
<div id="id_1"></div>
<div id="id_2"></div>
<div id="id_3"></div>
<div id="id_4"></div>
```

And here is my css code

```
<style>
#id_1:hover #id_2{background-color:red;}
#id_1:hover #id_3{background-color:red;}
#id_1:hover #id_4{background-color:red;}
#id_2:hover #id_4{background-color:red;}
</style>
```

This hover is why not working ? Someone help me ?

I need when i hover #id_1, will change backgroundcolor #id_2

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Having e.g. `#id_1 #id_2` implies that the `#id_2` element is a child of `#id_1`, which obviously isn't true.

Comment: You can't do that in css unless you take `id_1` out of  parent or create some other sibling or parent-child relationship, https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1737/, also that is not html markup you posted originally

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because those divs are siblings so you need to use [`general sibling selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) or `~`

```
#id_1:hover ~ div
```

This will match all sibling elements of `#id_1` with type of `div`, and you can use that instead of writing separate selector for each `div`

```
#id_2:hover ~ #id_4
```

This will match only sibling element of `id_2` that has `#id_4`, if you only want to match div you can add `div#id_4`

```css
#id_1:hover ~ div {
  background-color: red;
}

#id_2:hover ~ #id_4 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="id_1">div</div>
<div id="id_2">div</div>
<div id="id_3">div</div>
<div id="id_4">div</div>
```

If you just want to change color of next sibling element when you hover over `#id_1` you can use [`adjacent sibling selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) or `+`

```css
#id_1:hover + div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="id_1">div</div>
<div id="id_2">div</div>
<div id="id_3">div</div>
<div id="id_4">div</div>
```

Comment: So why not is working my code. Can you look my question, i added attachment. Thanks.

Comment: @JimmyPuaaKuaa because you id1 is not a sibling of id2.  I think you should learn the basics of css if you are having trouble with the concept of children and siblings - your code in the picture is not laid out in the same way as your code in the question

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CSS attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). More specifically, `[attr^=value]` which

> Represents elements with an attribute name of attr whose value is
> prefixed (preceded) by value.

and in your case it would be `div[id^='id_']:hover`.

As an example adapted from [Andrzej Gorgoń](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53697668/5675325)

```css
div {
    background: red;  
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

div[id^='id_']:hover {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="id_1"></div>
<div id="id_2"></div>
<div id="id_3"></div>
<div id="id_4"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This selector:

```
element1 element2
```

Works when element2 is child of element1

Your css is true when the #id_2 is a child of #id_1

You can change your code to this:

```
#id_1:hover + div{background-color: red;}
```

Comment: This is not child. I need when i hover #id_1, change #id_2 background-color.