# Apply :hover to multiple #id

Tags: html, css, hover

How to apply a :hover property to multiple html elements' IDs (all different from the one I am hovering over)?
Formulated in english, my program would look like : "If I am hovering over #item1, hide #item2 and #item3 and #item4." (So then I can go on "And if I am hovering over #item2, hide #item1 and #item5" etc.)

So for a CSS like :

```
 #generalID #item1:hover+#item2 {
 visibility:hidden;
}
```

How can I add more items to #item2 ? I didn't find the answer in the css tutorials or forums I have read... And tried unsuccessfully things like

```
 #generalID #item1:hover+#item2+#item3 {
 visibility:hidden;
}
```

But then the property only applies to the last item I mentioned. Or :

```
 #generalID #item1:hover+#item2 {
 visibility:hidden;
}
 #generalID #item1:hover+#item3 {
 visibility:hidden;
}
```

But then it only applies to the first one.

How to?

Comment: CSS alone is useless, you need to show the HTML also

Comment: Hi Temani Afif, I didn't show my html because I thought this CSS would make it clear enough : a rank of HTML items all similar but with different IDs

Comment: "How to" depends on the structure of your HTML. What you have will only work if all of the items you're targeting are adjacent siblings. Also, it is likely unnecessary to have `#generalID` in there...

Comment: again, CSS alone is useless ... CSS has no sense without HTML. CSS alone will never be clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wildcard expression selector in your css to match multiple similar ids names. Example below:

```
div {
   background: red;  
   width: 50px;
   height: 100px;
   float: left;
   margin-right: 5px;
}

div[id^='item']:hover {
  background: blue;
}
```

And fiddle for you to check it:

https://jsfiddle.net/k5t2jxog/3/

UPDATE:
The answer that had been accepted:

HTML:

```
<div id="item1" data-hide-on-hover="2,5" data-hide-enable>
</div>
<div id="item2">
</div>
<div id="item3">
</div>
<div id="item4">
</div>
<div id="item5" data-hide-on-hover="1,3" data-hide-enable>
</div>
<div id="item6">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-hide-enable]');

elements.forEach(function(element) {

    // add on hover effects
    element.addEventListener("mouseover", function(element) {
        var elementsIdsToHide = element.target.getAttribute("data-hide-on-hover").trim().split(',');

        var cssSelector = elementsIdsToHide.map(function(item) {
            return "#item" + item;
        });

        var elementsToHide = document.querySelectorAll(cssSelector.join(","));

        elementsToHide.forEach(function(elemToHide) {
            elemToHide.setAttribute("style", "opacity: 0")
        });

    })

    element.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(element) {
        console.log(document.querySelectorAll("[id^='item']"));
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='item']");

        elements.forEach(function(elem) {
            elem.setAttribute("style", "opacity: 1");
        });
    })

})
```

Comment: Thanks Andrzej but this doesn't really match my needs... first I need to select some specific items and not all of them from the same list. And then the declaration needs to apply to specific items different from the one I am hovering over.

Comment: Did you consider JavaScript solution? If so then I can present you one.

Comment: Well sure, please do ^^ as Aniket offered some JQuery, I can learn !

Comment: Here you go. I provide customizable html, where you can set in attributes, which ones you want to hide after mouse over.

https://jsfiddle.net/4sc85onv/22/

If you have question feel free to ask :)

Comment: Thank you so much Andrzej !! It works, only there is one detail : as I am retrieving the mouse pointer from the hovered item, all of the items are flashing out during half a second. Is there a way to correct this?

Comment: I have created another question for the JS glitching problem. Thank you very much !

Comment: You can operate with an css class switching instead of changing the exact style property. You can for example add in css class for hiding and in JavaScript try to add class to the element: `elemToHide.classList.addClass("exampleClassName")`.

Comment: Mh, I did it and added the class to JS as var elemToHide, but it's still glitching

Comment: Hmm... I should take a look at the actual code of yours to see what really is happening. Do you have some JS Fiddle?

Answer (score 2):

Knowing your HTML would be very useful.

The `+` combinator means that `#item2` has to be immediately after `#item1`. This is why `#item3`, `#item4`, and `#item5` never have anything applied to them, because (I assume) the `#item2` element is always between the two.

You might want to look into the `~` combinator instead, which matches any other elements that *come after* the element being hovered.

So, either you write a lot of CSS:

```
 #generalID #item1:hover ~ #item2,
 #generalID #item1:hover ~ #item3,
 #generalID #item1:hover ~ #item4,
 #generalID #item1:hover ~ #item5 {
   visibility: hidden;
 }
```

You can make it simpler to write with a CSS preprocessor like [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/) or [Stylus](http://stylus-lang.com/):

```
#generalID #item1:hover {
  & ~ #item2, 
  & ~ #item3, 
  & ~ #item4, 
  & ~ #item5 {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

Or you utilise wildcards, understanding the [support limitations](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2) they have:

```
#generalID #item1:hover ~ [id^='item'] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

However, even with switching from `+` to `~`, there is no possible CSS selector that can be written that would hide `#item1` when `#item2` is hovered, since (I assume) `#item1` is *before* `#item2`.

For maximum compatibility, you have to write JavaScript (this with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)):

```
$("#generalID > *").hover(function(){
  $(this).siblings().css("visibility", "hidden");
}, function(){
  $(this).siblings().css("visibility", "initial");
});
```

Alternatively, rethink your approach in HTML to make something that's more comfortable to write CSS selectors for.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think you totally understood what I needed... The first solution you gave me could be perfect but doesn't seem to work, once again it only applies to the first item specified.

Comment: My HTML is quite long but the part that interests us is made out of this kind of elements : <div id=generalMap> <a href="box26.html" class=S id=s26>box26</a> <a href="box27.html" class=S id=s27>box27</a> </div> (and there are 37 boxes)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use jQuery for this:

```
if($('#item1').is(":hover"))
{
    $('#item2').css("visibility", "hidden");
};
```

Comment: Thanks Aniket, I have very few knowledge of jQuery so I will try to apply this correctly and tell you if it works !

Comment: No problem. Try to learn jQuery if you can - it's a great tool to use.