# CSS hover selector doesn't showing anything

Tags: html, css, hover

So I'm trying to learn HTML and CSS with solving the frontendmentor challenges. This one's new so i couldn't find a solution to lookup my problem. My problem is; i haven't done any hover effect before so, i tried to make by myself and i couldn't, it should work actually i mean everything looks good but idk. Every help appreciated.

```css
#nft {
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

#view {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 150px;
}

#nft:hover #view {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="nft-img">
  <img id="view" src="./images/icon-view.svg" alt="">
  <img id="nft" src="./images/image-equilibrium.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Try to read about `hover`: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Answer (score 1):

This question is poorly written, please have a look at the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

However, you haven't defined a height property on your elements, because of this, they are invisible. By default, the height of a block element is the height of the content, and the width is the length of the page. Check out [this](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs193x/cs193x.1176/lectures/05/block-inline) for further information.

My above answer does not help you, I did not see that you included images. The problem should be solved with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43000728/14231863). Your selector `#nft:hover #view` does not work, because these elements are siblings. And also keep the `z-index` in mind.

Comment: More generally, the width is the length of the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

try to change to:

```
#nft:hover ~ #view{
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: This would work, but it would achieve a different result.

Comment: #nft:hover ~ #view

Comment: Yeah, I already provided that answer above.